# Compute table name to join from row value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have tables that look somewhat like this:

```
Table name: products

ID      PRODUCT_ID      TYPE       PRICE      ...
1       111             computer   xxx
2       222             book       xx
3       333             computer   xxxx

----------------------------------------------------------------

Table name: products_computer

ID      PRODUCT_ID      CPU     RAM      ....
1       111             amd     16
2       333             intel   8

----------------------------------------------------------------

Table name: products_book

ID      PRODUCT_ID      AUTHOR          YEAR_PUBLISHED        ....
1       222             Stephen King    xxxx
```

As you can see, in table `products` every single product is listed with columns of what they have in common ( like the price ), and the other tables contain specific information for that product type.

Now lets say we want to list every product independend of their type ordered by the price, and also include the specific information of the `products_*` tables in the query, to not manually make a second query just to retrieve that information.

While I hardly ever use databases and SQL, my inexperience ran into various pitfalls trying to concat strings to build the `products_*` table name for a `JOIN` or make a "middle table" that maps the `procucts.TYPE` value to the actual table name, where I found later in the documentation that it simply doesn't work trying to "bind" a column/row value as the table name.

Is there any "trick" to make this work ( having everything in 1 query ), or do I really have to make a second query manually in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, then you need all columns from `products` table and their corresponding information (if any) from `products_computer` and `products_book` tables.

If this is the scenario then I think all you need here is multiple `LEFT JOIN` SQL statements

**SQL Statements**

```
SELECT products.product_id, type , price, cpu, ram, author, year_published
FROM products
LEFT JOIN products_computer ON products.product_id = products_computer.product_id
LEFT JOIN products_book ON products.product_id = products_book.product_id
ORDER BY price
```

**Output**

[image: All products from products table and their corresponding informations]

Comment: From all answers, this seems to be the one needing the least workload and maintenance while delivering the wanted result.

Comment: +1 This is the more elegant solution. I originally went down the `UNION` path when not joining back to the `products` table but omitted the sort on price. When the sort on `price` becomes necessary, clearly it's simpler to just join both tables back to `products`. The option of defining a view to use this query still applies.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with a [`UNION`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) statement.

```
SELECT 
    products.ID AS ID, products.PRODUCT_ID AS PRODUCT_ID, products.PRICE AS PRICE, products_computer.CPU AS CPU, products_computer.RAM AS RAM,
    null as AUTHOR, null as YEAR_PUBLISHED
  FROM products_computer
  JOIN products ON products_computer.PRODUCT_ID = products.PRODUCT_ID
UNION
SELECT 
    products.ID AS ID, products.PRODUCT_ID AS PRODUCT_ID, products.PRICE AS PRICE, null as CPU, null as RAM, 
    products_book.AUTHOR AS AUTHOR, products_book.YEAR_PUBLISHED AS YEAR_PUBLISHED 
  FROM products_book
  JOIN products ON products_book.PRODUCT_ID = products.PRODUCT_ID
ORDER BY PRICE
```

The two separate queries are joined into one larger query. For this to work, the columns selected in each of the `SELECT` statements need to be the same. Note how I've `SELECT`ed null values for the columns in the *other* table.

Each of the individual `SELECT`s also joins back to the `products` based on the common PRODUCT_ID column. Price is included, and there's an [ORDER BY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) statement at the end to sort by PRICE.

This is the output from the query:

[image: Ordered Query Output]

As per @Zero's comment, it's possible to store a query as a view. As a once off operation, execute the query as a view definition:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_products_all AS
       SELECT products.ID AS ID,
              products.PRODUCT_ID AS PRODUCT_ID,
              products.PRICE AS PRICE,
              products_computer.CPU AS CPU,
              products_computer.RAM AS RAM,
              NULL AS AUTHOR,
              NULL AS YEAR_PUBLISHED
         FROM products_computer
              JOIN products
                ON products_computer.PRODUCT_ID = products.PRODUCT_ID
       UNION
       SELECT products.ID AS ID,
              products.PRODUCT_ID AS PRODUCT_ID,
              products.PRICE AS PRICE,
              NULL AS CPU,
              NULL AS RAM,
              products_book.AUTHOR AS AUTHOR,
              products_book.YEAR_PUBLISHED AS YEAR_PUBLISHED
         FROM products_book
              JOIN products
                ON products_book.PRODUCT_ID = products.PRODUCT_ID
        ORDER BY PRICE;
```

... after which the data may be accessed via:

```
SELECT * FROM vw_products_all
```

... or, more explicitly (good practice):

```
SELECT ID,
    PRODUCT_ID,
    PRICE,
    CPU,
    RAM,
    AUTHOR,
    YEAR_PUBLISHED
FROM vw_products_all
```

The output is the same as the original query's output.

Comment: I can't really follow how products are ordered by price in your example. Also, this makes me write out all the columns and specific `products_*` tables, and there are far more than I included in my smalled down version in my question. This could become some monster of a query, rather sooner than later.

Comment: @Slyps You can store queries as a "view" in the database itself. A "view" does not contain any actual data (just the query) but one can use it like a normal table.

Comment: This `VIEW` is indeed interesting, but it doesn't really help on the size and workload issue of creating the query string for this case. What if there are 50 more product types ( and hence 50 more `product_*` tables ). I can't imagine this would be good practise in the world of SQL pros ( compared to creating a second query fetching the results of the specific `products_*` tables as I iterate over the results of the `products` table )

Comment: @Slyps This is true. But that goes back to application design. What you asked for is a way of combining the values from two child tables with a common parent, and listing out all of the data from each child table. The solution described above does that. The context of the underlying problem was omitted. The question asked to "list every product independent of their type ordered by the price, and also include the specific information of the products_* tables in the query". The method described above is certainly strongly-tied to specific implementation of each table.

Comment: @CJBS Yes I know and agree. I didn't mean to say your answer isn't a valid answer to my question, I meant to just input my thoughts to clarify my question for parts I might have described unclear. As a hint for future readers of this question that might have an idea. Ofcourse, if your answer is still the only one until I gave up waiting, then I will obviously accept it, even if it's not what I hoped for.

Comment: @Slyps When you have 50 tables with different columns, then you have to handle them separately.

Comment: Why are you using UNION and not UNION ALL?

Comment: @CL The assumption here is that the product keys would make the output unique, thus there's no need for duplicate rows.

Comment: @CJBS But it is UNION that make the additional checks for duplicate rows.

Answer (score -1):

[According to Larry Wall your instinct to be too lazy to write the code yourself is right](http://threevirtues.com/). Generating a view bringing all those tables together is fairly easy. Try this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE VIEW vw_products_all AS ' +
    SUBSTRING((
        SELECT [text()] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            ' UNION ALL {1}SELECT P.id, P.PRODUCT_ID, P.Name, {2} FROM dbo.products AS P INNER JOIN dbo.{0} AS PS ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PS.PRODUCT_ID'
            , '{0}', QUOTENAME(O.name))
            , '{1}', CHAR(10))
            , '{2}', SUBSTRING((
                SELECT [text()] = ', ' + ISNULL(QUOTENAME(C_this.name), 'NULL as ' + QUOTENAME(C_all.name))
                FROM sys.columns AS C_all
                    LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS C_this
                        ON O.object_id = C_this.object_id
                        AND C_all.name = C_this.name
                WHERE OBJECT_NAME(C_all.object_id) LIKE 'product[_]%'
                    AND c_all.name NOT IN ('PRODUCT_ID', 'ID')
                ORDER BY C_all.name
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 2, 10000000000000))
        FROM sys.objects AS O
        WHERE name LIKE 'product[_]%'
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 11, 1000000000000)

SELECT @SQL
```

Comment: Im sorry for your effort, I should've said that Im looking for an sqlite solution instead of only tagging it.

Comment: The OP indicated that he's using sqlite, not SQL Server.